# Can I scale up part of an image by secluding an area?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm using html5 canvas and JS.

I'm drawing an image on the canvas with `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`. This image is 15x15 black square, with a 1 pixel wide white border: so 16x16 total.

Is there a way to read image data in JS, and only scale up the border width of that image. So, leave the inner black square 15x15, but make the white border width 3 pixels wide?

As far as I can tell, the `CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData()` can only select an area, but you cannot seclude an area, to use the rest.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why not add 2 pixel white border to the image?

Comment: Just an easy example.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the size of a canvas without clearing its content. The only way to resize the canvas is to create a second canvas, copy the existing content to the new canvas while adding the new content.

The following function will pad a canvas with a boarder by creating a second canvas. Filling it with the padding color, adding the original canvas image to it. Then resize the original and copying the new content to it.

```
// padCanvas(canvas, padAmount, padColor)
// canvas :    HTMLCanvasElement Canvas to pad
//             Note all state setting on the input canvas will be reset
// padAmount : Number Amount to pad canvas in pixels
// padColor :  String Color of padding as CSS style color string. eg "White"
// Returns the original canvas,
function padCanvas(canvas, padAmount, padColor) {
     // create a canvas with the padded size
     const can = Object.assign(
          document.createElement("canvas"), {
              width:  canvas.width + padAmount * 2, 
              height: canvas.height + padAmount * 2
          }
     );

     // add padding color and source (image)
     const ctx = can.getContext("2d");
     ctx.fillStyle = padColor;
     ctx.fillRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
     ctx.drawImage(canvas, padAmount, padAmount);

     // Resize original image and add new content
     Object.assign(canvas, {width: can.width, height: can.height});
     canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(can, 0, 0);
     return canvas;
}
```